# ¿Como convertir un string de fecha a timestamp?

Tags: python, string, date, timestamp

Eso pues, tengo estos strings:

```
"23-Sep-2021"
"8:35:42 AM"
```

Y quiero pasar cada string a su respectivo timestamp:

```
1632355200
30942
```

Respectivamente.

Con respecto a la de fecha, estaba probando esto:

```
import datetime
import time

date = "23-Sep-2021"
date2 = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())
```

Pero al parecer es sólo para formatos `23/09/2021`

Con respecto a la de hora, no se me ocurre nada

Comment: Prueba con `strptime(date, "%d-%b-%Y")`, mi única duda son con los meses en español

Comment: ah, me olvide de comentar que los meses estan en español

Comment: Por eso te hice el comentario para que lo pruebes, no se como se comporta en estos caso, el `%b` es para indicar un mes de tres letras

Comment: oye, resulta que la fecha estaba en este formato dia/mes/año, ya arregle el tema de la fecha, ahora no se como hacer con la hora

Comment: Fijate la documentación de `strptime()` : https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes  seguro están todos los formatos que necesitas para procesar esa hora

Comment: Para español usa `import locale` y establece el idioma de la fecha y hora local en español usando `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME,'es_ES.UTF-8')`

Comment: puse esto: ````print(time.mktime(datetime.strptime(time, "%I:%M:%S %p").timetuple()))```` y me sale esto en consola: ````mktime argument out of range````

Comment: cuidado con usar una variable llamada `time` por que ya existe el modulo